# Stateless CDI Managed bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, ejb, cdi

I cant find a bean in JNDI on my jboss when I deploy a WAR file that has jsf 2.2 I get the following exception. Anyone know why this is happening? (the bean is in JNDI, I see that Jboss binds it and I have tried with all sorts of lookup paths)

```
Deployment "vfs:///C:/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/all/deploy/web.war" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not resolve @EJB reference: [EJB Reference: beanInterface 'se.questify.services.entities.ExamServiceBase', beanName 'null', mappedName 'null', lookupName
 'null', owning unit 'AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@1298976756{vfs:///C:/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/all/deploy/web.war}'] for environment entry: env/ExamService/local in unit AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@1298976756{vfs:///C:/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/all/deploy/web.war}
```

Jboss stack on deploy of ejb.jar

```
INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.nointerface.impl.jndi.AbstractNoInterfaceViewBinder] Binding the following entry in Global JNDI for bean:ExamServiceBase

        ExamServiceBase/no-interface -> EJB3.1 no-interface view
```

EJB

```
@Stateless
@Named("examServiceBase")
public class ExamServiceBase{

    public String getHello(){
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

JSF code

```html
<h:body>    
    <h1>JSF 2 Demo</h1>
    <h:form>
        <h:outputLabel value="#{examServiceBase.hello}" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't have both. You can't have both `@Named` and `@Stateless`, they're mutually exclusive. [From Oracle:](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjfzi.html)

> A top-level java class is a managed bean if... it meets all the following conditions:
>
> - It is not annotated with an EJB component-defining annotation or declared as an EJB bean class in *ejb-jar.xml*

Comment: According to Adam Bien it should be possible http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/ejb_3_1_killed_the

Comment: @Marthin, [oracle begs to differ](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjfzi.html)

Comment: Try using more recent than JBoss 6, that's old and what you're seeing is probably a bug.